# A inicialização do objeto pode ser simplificada

Tags: c#, xamarin

Após ter feito umas atualizações nos pacotes nuget(18), fui compilar meu projeto e dá esse erro:

> A inicialização do objeto pode ser simplificada

Ele aponta para esses arquivos em meu código.

```
GridTextColumn dataLib = new GridTextColumn();
```

Aqui a classe completa

```
public class Control
    {
        SfDataGrid dataGrid = new SfDataGrid();
        DataService dataService = new DataService();
        public async void CriaDataGrid()
        {
            dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            GridTextColumn dataLib = new GridTextColumn();
            dataLib.MappingName = "DataLib";
            dataLib.HeaderText = "Data";
            dataLib.Width = 80;
            dataLib.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start;
            dataLib.CellTextSize = 9;

            GridTextColumn cliente = new GridTextColumn();
            cliente.MappingName = "Cliente";
            cliente.HeaderText = "Cliente";
            cliente.Width = 180;
            cliente.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start;
            cliente.CellTextSize = 9;

            GridTextColumn vendedor = new GridTextColumn();
            vendedor.MappingName = "Vendedor";
            vendedor.HeaderText = "Vendedor";
            vendedor.Width = 180;
            vendedor.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start;
            vendedor.CellTextSize = 9;

            GridTextColumn filial = new GridTextColumn();
            filial.MappingName = "Filial";
            filial.HeaderText = "Filial";
            filial.Width = 100;
            filial.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start;
            filial.CellTextSize = 9;

            dataGrid.Columns.Add(dataLib);
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(cliente);
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(vendedor);
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(filial);

            //dataGrid.AllowResizingColumn = true;
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = await dataService.GetLiberaAsync();
            dataGrid.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Single;
            dataGrid.SelectionChanged += DataGrid_SelectionChanged;
        }
        void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, GridSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
        }
    }
```

**EDIT1**

Versão do VS2017
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso é um erro de compilação ou um warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não é um erro, é um *warning* que diz que a inicialização pode ser feita de uma maneira mais legível e organizada.

A dica é que você inicialize os objetos assim:

```
GridTextColumn dataLib = new GridTextColumn
{
    MappingName = "DataLib",
    HeaderText = "Data",
    Width = 80,
    TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start,
    CellTextSize = 9
};
```

Além disso, provavelmente, você vai receber um *warning* pedindo para usar `var` do lado esquerdo da atribuição, já que o tipo pode ser inferido.

Comment: é um warning, mas não compila e nem implanta, por isso eu abri o post.

Comment: Reiniciei o VS e desapareceu esse erro sem que eu fizesse alguma coisa. De qualquer forma, vou fechar o post com a resposta do LINQ para não ficar aberto, sem conclusão, pois a abordagem dele para o título do post está correta.

Comment: @pnet Estive vasculhando o GitHub e parece que realmente o Roslyn deu uma complicada que não deveria com alguns _warnings_. Você poderia confirmar a versão completa do seu Visual Studio?

Comment: Editei o post e pus a versão lá